# Javacards IDE, and JCOP tools for eclipse unavailable to download

Tags: eclipse, smartcard, javacard, jcop

I'm starting to develop in JavaCard (more specifically JavaCard 2.2.2).

I'm searching for tools to develop in JavaCard. I want an IDE that incorporates both an emulator and a debugger. The eclipse plugin JCOP tools from IBM seems to do that, but for some reason I can't find it online. Some forums point to the link http://www.zurich.ibm.com/jcop/download/eclipse/, but this link no longer works...

Anyone knows what's going on? Have JCOP tools been discontinued? If so, can anyone suggest another IDE capable of those features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JCOP tools is no longer maintained by IBM. All support activities related to the JCOP operating system were handed over to NXP in 2007 (?). You might be able to get further information from NXP directly (tools.jcop@nxp.com), but don't expect them to respond if your request is not backed by a real business case.

The toolchains for Java Card development (various versions) is available directly from Oracle (through their website). The toolchain can be used from the commandline and also supports ANT tasks. For upload to real cards, you can use open Global Platform tools (e.g. GPShell).

Comment: Hey, never knew about the ant tasks, it took them a while to catch up with me, but there it is :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes May I ask you what is the ANT tasks? I google it, but all I found are related to Apache! is this ANT tasks, the same one that I found? please mention me in your comment.Thank you.

Comment: There is a set of Ant tasks within the JCDK. That means you should be able to integrate the tools within an Ant build file (`build.xml`). Note that support for these tasks is sketchy. Previously I wrote my own tasks using the Java API of the tools. The Ant system is pluggable, you can predefined tasks like `javac` - the compiler,define tasks yourself - or import tasks. Ant is like `make` (used for C/C++ mainly) but it only declares tasks instead of literally programming them using CLI tools.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GPJ or GPSHELL or JCMANAGER for uploading and deleting .cap files on real javacards. These are download links :

GPJ:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpj/
(Now GlobalPlatformPro https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro)

JCManager:
https://github.com/martinpaljak/jcManager

GPShell: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/globalplatform/files/GPShell/

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know is JCOP still available, but only directly from NXP and not for free.
And, since Oracle owns Java and Java Card, NetBeans makes it very easy to work with JavaCards (mostly JavaCard 3), but as long as you use the "classic applets" it will act as a 2.2.2

It also comes with a handy quick start guide https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/java-card.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the JCIDE to develop JavaCard Applet for **free**. It is an Integrated Development Environment designed specifically for the JavaCard programming language.

The JCIDE itself also comes with a **quick start video tutorial** to help you. Also I feel great in use process.

You can see more about JCIDE  in "https://github.com/Tolice/JCIDE/wiki"