# How can I use this file to develop JCOP smart cards?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, jcop

I have some *J3A080* and *J3A082* JCOP Smart cards. I gained this below file from an unusual way! I know that this file is related to my cards. But I don't have any idea how can I use it! It has only 2KB size?!
What kind of software I must have? I think I must load it in a software, but what is it? Eclipse? Where I can find that software?

[image]

I appreciate your help and consideration.

Comment: For your information, you can use Netbeans 6.9 and after for javacard, It doesn't need any extra plugins to work with Javacard. JCop is not free anymore and is  not easy to buy serial number in your location. There's two other solutions, First use eClipse and GPShell, Second is using Netbeans. Of course there's other solutions which I haven't got any info about those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is a JCOP Shell script, you can open it in any text editor and have a look or make some changes.

Using JCOP Shell script you can open SC readers, select javacard applets, send some APDUs to your applet, write your own testing scenarios etc. JCOP Shell script is basically a batch of commands to your SC reader. It is very similar to Linux shell scripts.

JCOP Shell scripts are usually run from Eclipse plugin called JCOP Tools provided by NXP. Unfortunately, this plugin is no longer free and there is no (legal) way to get it. It requires registration key. Ask NXP, if they could send you some trial version or something like that.

Related issue: [Javacards IDE, and JCOP tools for eclipse unavailable to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675804/javacards-ide-and-jcop-tools-for-eclipse-unavailable-to-download)

Comment: Do you have any versionof JCOP Tools?

Comment: May I have your email address? :D