# How can i select Hello World Applet from my SAM card and then how send APDU for receive "48 65 6C 6C 6F" that it is equivalent with "Hello" String

Tags: applet, javacard, apdu, smartcard-reader

I am very newbie in javacard and applets.

I now have a Hello World project according this [link](https://umer555.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/java-card-hello-world-applet/) and i made its .cap

file, .exp file and .jca file. I have "DE-ABCM_TB" reader and a SAM card also.

i already loaded my Hello World project to the SAM card .

Now How can i select  Hello World Applet from my SAM card and then how send APDU

for receive "48 65 6C 6C 6F" that it is equivalent with "Hello" String. (with

which commands? and with which platform that is free and exists on the net?)

Comment: What SAM chip do you use?

Comment: It is standard java card.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to download the JCOP plugin for eclipse , then you need to activate JCOP tools to start writing in the card. To activate JCOP tools , just start a new javacard project in eclipse ; and it will ask you if you have an activation code from NXP , or do you have a JCOP card : Put your card in the reader and select the choice of using an already activated card. And you should have all the tools then (Eclipse/Javacard Plugin / JCOP tools installed /JCOP tools activated using your card)

Comment: How can i get JCOP tools? I cant access it on the internet.

Comment: this can help you @soheylaab  :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675804/javacards-ide-and-jcop-tools-for-eclipse-unavailable-to-download

Comment: Why do suggest to use JCOP tools? @soheylaab did not even reveal what type of SAM it is (Is it a JCOP card? Or does it contain some other OS?) There's plenty of (open) tools available unless soheylaab requires any JCOP specific functionality.

Comment: I get "gpj" from this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpj/ . Now How can i use it for work with my SAM card ( list applets, install applets, select applets or sending APDU Commands to card via gpj?

Comment: Can you explain more about the type of your SAM card ? I though you are using the same card as mentionned in the sample project . Are you sure it's a JCOP ? Otherwise , you can use other tools if it's not a JCOP . Please tell me more about your card

Comment: assume my card is a JCOP. Now How Can i select my applet with AID 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00? I already install my .cap file in other way on the my card.

Comment: Download **OpenSC** tool from here (https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki). Then you can sends APDU to your card and select the applet using this command :  `>opensc-tool -s 00a40400 0b 0102030405060708090000` in command prompt

Comment: As I think you are Persian, I think I can help you better if you send me an email ("ebr.ghasemi@gmail")